# Better way to implement 'like tweet' functionality with react native and redux

Tags: react-native, redux

Suppose I'm writing a Twitter clone but much simpler. Here's a picture of what a 'post' looks like

[image]

In the bottom of a post, there's a what I'd call `Social Bar` thing, which contains 3 buttons, `comment`, `message` and `like` button. `comment` button lets users comment on the post, `message` button lets users message the owner of the post, and `like` button lets users 'like' the post. Upon pressing `like` button, the color of the button will flip to red, pressing it again will make it gray again.

What I have so far is that, I make `Social Bar` a pure component, which has it's own `state`: `commentCount`, `liked`, `likeCount` (`liked` indicates whether this user has liked this post before, if so, `liked` = true, and therefore, the color of `like` button will be red initially, upon pressing the button, `liked` and `likeCount` properties will change accordingly).

My problem is, when users press the post, I will take them to another page, where they can view the comments on the post, like this:
[image]

You can see that in this `Post Content` page, users can also 'like' the post. If users decide to 'like' the post (`like` button will be red), then the `like` button in the first picture should also the updated. How should I implement this? Currently, I am using `redux`, whenever I 'like' a post, I 'broadcast' the `postId` of the post to every `Social Bar`, and if the `id` matches, then update the `like` button. Yes, it works, however, every time I press `like` button, it takes about 1 second for the color to change. What I want is for the button the change immediately, like Twitter and Facebook. How do I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that you're not using redux the way it was intented to use.

Instead of having components with its own state you should manage state with redux store (https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html#store).

Below you can find a simple react application. There are 2 sections in the app: "all posts" and "specific post". In the "all posts" section you can see 5 posts, each with its own like button and likes counter. In the "specific post" section it renders just a single post (post #2).

See how everything stays in sync when you click "like" on post #2 no matter in which section you click (all posts / specific post).

```js
const createStore = window.Redux.createStore;
const combineReducers = window.Redux.combineReducers;
const connect = window.ReactRedux.connect;
const Provider = window.ReactRedux.Provider;

const postsData = [
  { id: 1, likes: 0 },
  { id: 2, likes: 1 },
  { id: 3, likes: 0 },
  { id: 4, likes: 3 },
  { id: 5, likes: 2 },
];

// First, we're defining the initial state
const initialState = {
  posts: postsData,
  postsLikeCounters: postsData.reduce((out, post) => {
    return {
      ...out,
      [post.id]: post.likes
    };
  }, {})
};


// Then we're defining our reducers. Here I have 3 reducers:
// posts, postsLikes and postsLikeCounters
// Obviously you may want to use other data structures
function posts(state=posts, action) {
  return state;
}

function postsLikes(state={}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LIKE_POST':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.post.id]: true
      };
    case 'UNLIKE_POST':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.post.id]: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function postsLikeCounters(state={}, action) {
  let value;

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LIKE_POST':
      value = state[action.post.id] || 0;
      
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.post.id]: value + 1
      };
    case 'UNLIKE_POST':
      value = state[action.post.id] || 0;

      return {
        ...state,
        [action.post.id]: Math.max(value - 1, 0)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// Now we're combining all reducers into a single rootReducer
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  posts,
  postsLikes,
  postsLikeCounters
});

// With rootReducer and the initialState we're ready to create our store
// To put it simple - store is a single place to keep the whole application state (instead of keeping it in specific components)
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);


// Now we're going to define our components
const Post = (props) => (
  <div style={ {border:'1px solid #000', margin: 5} }>
    <strong>Post #{props.post.id}</strong>
    {props.liked ? (
      <button onClick={()=>props.onUnlike(props.post)}>
        Unlike
      </button>
    ) : (
      <button onClick={()=>props.onLike(props.post)}>
        Like
      </button>
    )}
    <span>({props.likes} likes)</span>
  </div>
)

const Posts = (props) => (
  <div>
    { props.posts.map(post => (
      <Post 
        key={post.id}
        post={post}
        likes={props.postsLikeCounters[post.id]}
        liked={props.postsLikes[post.id]}
        onLike={props.onLike}
        onUnlike={props.onUnlike} />
    ) ) }
  </div>
);


// Define onLike and onUnlike actions
const onLike = (post) => ({ type: 'LIKE_POST', post });
const onUnlike = (post) => ({ type: 'UNLIKE_POST', post });


// Create components that uses redux's store to manage state
const PostsWithLikes = connect(
  function(state){
    return {
      posts: state.posts,
      postsLikes: state.postsLikes,
      postsLikeCounters: state.postsLikeCounters
    };
  },
  {
    onLike,
    onUnlike
  }
)(Posts)

const SpecificPost = connect(
  function(state, ownProps){
    const id = ownProps.id;
    const post = state.posts.find(post => post.id === id);

    return {
      post: post,
      liked: state.postsLikes[id],
      likes: state.postsLikeCounters[id]
    };
  },
  {
    onLike,
    onUnlike
  }
)(Post);


// And we're ready to put it all together:
const App = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <h1>all posts:</h1>
      <PostsWithLikes />
      <div>
        <h2>specific post:</h2>
        <SpecificPost id={2} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  App,
  document.getElementById('rootElement')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.7.2/redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.6/react-redux.js"></script>

<div id="rootElement"></div>
```